# Como fazer funcionar tecla de atalho em Tadvglowbutton

Tags: delphi

Possuo um `form` para utilizar de base para criação de outros utilizando o componente `Tadvglowbutton`. No `form` de exemplo funcionando teclas de atalho em todos os botões deste tipo, porém mesmo depois de eu copiar o botão para meu novo `form` os atalhos não funcionam.

Já verifiquei o código em busca de `procedures` que pudessem estar fazendo isso, mas só existem `procedures` super simples que apenas mostram mensagens na tela ou então abrem e fecham conexão com o banco de dados.

Abaixo encontra-se o código de um objeto do tipo `TAdvGlowButton` (este peguei do `form` que o atalho funciona, mas é o mesmo que o do outro `form`):

```
object AdvGlowButton4: TAdvGlowButton
  Left = 850
  Top = 3
  Width = 79
  Height = 32
  Caption = 'ESC | Sair'
  Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  ImageIndex = 49
  FocusType = ftHot
  NotesFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  NotesFont.Color = clWindowText
  NotesFont.Height = -11
  NotesFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
  NotesFont.Style = []
  ParentFont = False
  Picture.Data = {
    89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000018000000180806000000E0773D
    F8000000097048597300000EC400000EC401952B0E1B00000271494441544889
    B595CF4B545118869FD7B92B2504A145FE03D524D44C08416D74220C6A716F3F
    74D92A5C39D3A6949432312910E6EEDA15B472D10C41A510D63FA0F79242919B
    76B92842B268A3F3B5F028379D9944C7B339DC7BBEFBBCE73BF73BEF2733A3D6
    C816CA69A017C801278056B7B4022C02B3C05454F43FD762A89A40265F4A4B7A
    6466178126493233934432DEBD5F035E49BA1315FDA5FF0A64F2A57E605252B3
    FBF88DA49299CD4B5A76F1ED40A7A4C0CC7ADC267E9BD9401C064F6B0A640BE5
    5160C43DCE00856ABB4A0E778C21701EA800C351D19FD82190C9976E4A7A6266
    156054D27854F42BF5E089AC53921E98D92080A41B51D17FBE2590C9978E02F3
    EE58EEC56130B61B7015A187C0A0A455333B1587C117CF293E065A806949E37B
    813BCE087006E8923401F429932FA5CD6C0130491DF54A6E97599C941499D93A
    70CC03AE034DC0EBFDC201E230F8902D94DF03DDC0350FC8491250DE2F3C31CA
    927240B7071CB78D529A6BA0C09C63A63DA0CD65F0B58102CB8E79D803B07A86
    B4C7B1C9F4801F401B1BD7FF7B83F847DCFCCD033E0167812CB0D02081D36EFE
    E801B392CE015780670D1208DC3F7877E0176DD38B5E029725CD98D9A5380C2A
    890F0EC561B05A0D962D945351D15F4FC4A680B792BACC6C2A0E83BE4D2FBACD
    46D7EA917417D832BB5A708024DC71C6802EE0A7A421A86DD7F79D5DEFAA7C33
    F95293B3EB2127F4AF5D27521E35B31117346D66B7E230584AACB798D99F6D47
    980642493957FBC37118EC6C3809483F300934036BC034F0029807965D583BD0
    095C052E0029E017301015FDDA2D33B9AB036BFADB85805E49DD66D621A9D5C5
    AF008B92665DB5D42CEDBFC465552860CF4DD40000000049454E44AE426082}
  Transparent = True
  TabOrder = 8
  OnClick = bfecharClick
  Appearance.BorderColor = 14727579
  Appearance.BorderColorHot = 10079963
  Appearance.BorderColorDown = 4548219
  Appearance.BorderColorChecked = clBlack
  Appearance.Color = 15653832
  Appearance.ColorTo = 16178633
  Appearance.ColorChecked = 7915518
  Appearance.ColorCheckedTo = 11918331
  Appearance.ColorDisabled = 15921906
  Appearance.ColorDisabledTo = 15921906
  Appearance.ColorDown = 7778289
  Appearance.ColorDownTo = 4296947
  Appearance.ColorHot = 15465983
  Appearance.ColorHotTo = 11332863
  Appearance.ColorMirror = 15586496
  Appearance.ColorMirrorTo = 16245200
  Appearance.ColorMirrorHot = 5888767
  Appearance.ColorMirrorHotTo = 10807807
  Appearance.ColorMirrorDown = 946929
  Appearance.ColorMirrorDownTo = 5021693
  Appearance.ColorMirrorChecked = 10480637
  Appearance.ColorMirrorCheckedTo = 5682430
  Appearance.ColorMirrorDisabled = 11974326
  Appearance.ColorMirrorDisabledTo = 15921906
  Appearance.GradientHot = ggVertical
  Appearance.GradientMirrorHot = ggVertical
  Appearance.GradientDown = ggVertical
  Appearance.GradientMirrorDown = ggVertical
  Appearance.GradientChecked = ggVertical
end
```

Comment: Num formulário o `Tadvglowbutton` funciona e noutro não? Já experimentou deixar somente um `TAdvGlowButton` no projeto todo? Verifique se há um conflito de atalhos, você o [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) ou algo semelhante?

Comment: @Qmechanic73, era conflito de atalhos mesmo >.<

Comment: A combinação já estava em uso em outro lugar? Se quiser postar uma resposta explicando a resolução, só para não deixar a pergunta sem respostas. =)